# How V60 and Aeropress affect flavor

Tags: flavor, aeropress, v60

I've heard that the V60 is better for light roasts and the Aeropress is better for Medium to Dark roasts, but could someone describe how these two brewing devices affect the flavor of coffee brewed for the different roasts (and which, in turn, would be preferable)?

Comment: I should note that I have had good results brewing light roasts with the Aeropress, but have heard from other people that it is not so good for light roasts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sounds like the generalization that drip or pour over brewing is better for light roasts and stronger brewing methods are better for darker roasts.

I'll counter that by saying that I often use my Aeropress for lighter roasts and my Clever Dripper for dark roasts and those cups come out just fine.

The Aeropress makes a sort of quasi-espresso cup that isn't true espresso, but is much stronger than just strong coffee.  I've found that it is unsuitable or less than satisfactory for beans that aren't recommended for espresso brewing.  While the Aeropress allows less control over "brew" strength.  The V60 should be more flexible.  Varying the grind and pour speed should allow a level of control not present with an Aeropress.

Comment: It would seem that you could have the same level of control with an Aeropress by playing with the brew time, water temp, agitations (stirring), and the pressure you put on the plunger.

Comment: Brew time not so much.  As soon as you put the water in an Aeropress it starts draining, albiet slowly.  The extraction you want from it is the pressure generated by the push.  If you allow it to "brew" or drip, you are using it as a pourover rather than an Aeropress.

Comment: I use the inverted method when I don't want it to act at all like a drip.

Comment: Bravo to you!  It makes such a mess half the time anyway that I haven't mustered the courage to try any real experimentation with mine.